# Zstandart(zstd) - checking return

Tags: c++, zstd, zstandard

Can you please explain how the "ZSTD_isError" function works?

I check the return code from ZSTD_isError to be zero:

```
ZSTD_cParameter cParam;

ZSTD_bounds ZSTD_bounds_ =  ZSTD_cParam_getBounds(cParam);


status_error = ZSTD_isError(ZSTD_bounds_.error);  //ZSTD_isError RETURN 1.

if (status_error != 0)
{
    Std::cout << ZSTD_getErrorName(status_error)<< std::endl; //BUT - "No error detected"

    return 1;
}
```

I don't understand, the ZSTD_isError function returns 1, but after calling the ZSTD_getErrorName() function - it returns that "No error detected".

Explain, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage is:

```
if (ZSTD_isError(ZSTD_bounds_.error))
{
    std::cout << ZSTD_getErrorName(ZSTD_bounds_.error) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me that this is a joke :) This is the same code :)

Comment: `status_error` is not the same as `ZSTD_bounds_.error` ;-) You did equivalent of `ZSTD_getErrorName(ZSTD_isError(ZSTD_bounds_.error))`

Comment: I'm a little "blind" today, sorry :)